# How do I access an array from one viewcontroller in another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, uiviewcontroller

I am very new to the swift language and am trying to make an app that would do some basic calculations.  The problem I am running into is that I want to use the values from an array that is declared in one viewcontroller in another viewcontroller to do calculations.
I declare the array in the first viewcontroller like this:

```
var array2 = [Double]()
```

And then I have no idea how to access this in the second view controller.  I have tried looking at previous questions as well as online tutorials and have had no success.

Any help is greatly appreciated.  Thank you in advance.

Comment: how do you transition to 2nd VC?

Comment: Just pass it to the second VC when you prepareForSegue.

Comment: @Dustin I use a segue activated by a button on the first viewcontroller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in VC2 create global `var array2 = [Double]()`

add following override func to body of VC1

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    let DVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController2 //replace ViewController2 with the name of your 2nd VC
    DVC.array2 = array2
}
```

---

Overall, what you are doing is telling VC1 to copy VC1's array2 to VC2's array2, before the segue happens.

As your app becomes more complex, if your VC1 has more than 1 segue...meaning can go to multiple different VC's...you'll need to change your `prepareForSegue` so that it takes into account for this.

One way to do this is to change it to

```
override func prepareForSegue(segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: AnyObject?) {
    if segue.identifier == "SegueIdentifier you give to that particular segue in identityInspector" {
        let DVC = segue.destinationViewController as! ViewController2 //replace ViewController2 with the name of your 2nd VC
        DVC.array2 = array2
    }
}
```